# How to obtain a messing part of data knowing a specific symmetry?

Tags: plotting, data

ex. I have this data

```
data = Table[{x, y, Sin[5 x] Cos[3 y]}, {x, -0.1, 0.1, 0.01}, {y, -1, 
    0, 0.1}];
ListDensityPlot[Flatten[data, 1], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

assume that the system has a mirror symmetry at $y=0$, What is the efficient way to obtain the missing data for $y>0$ from the available `data` above? which should look like this

```
dataAll = 
  Table[{x, y, Sin[5 x] Cos[3 y]}, {x, -0.1, 0.1, 0.01}, {y, -1, 1, 
    0.1}];
ListDensityPlot[Flatten[dataAll, 1], 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may define a function that multiplies the y coordinate by -1 and map it to your data to get the data with y>0:

```
Map[({1, -1, 1} #) &, data, {2}]
```

With this you may plot the old and new data together:

```
data1 = Join[data, Map[({1, -1, 1} #) &, data, {2}]];
ListDensityPlot[Flatten[data1, 1], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]